# When creating CLIENT ID: "An unexpected error has occurred. We're looking into it."

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am getting "An unexpected error has occurred. We're looking into it." when creating CLIENT ID

It did not happened before.

But recently I follow the new guide by Stephen Wylie, delete the whole project and start fresh

The first 2 times i delete and create new API project, it was ok.

But today I try again, and the error appears.
I cannot continue right now.

Another side question, when will the official Android sample be posted?
It had been promised for few months.
Unlike dropbox, box, skydrive, they all have very good sample that allows people to integrate into their app in few hours or even less than half hour if you are experienced.

Comment: The problem is previously I have created a CLIENT ID for Installed Application (Android type) with particular package name, lets say (com.example.xxx).

Now when I delete the whole API project, somehow the (com.example.xxx) still stucked with the server.

So whenever I create new API project, insert (com.example.xxx) it will cause error.

So the solution is to use another new package name.

But this also require you to change your package name in your code, it is quite a trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package name/signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1) pair has to be unique and that includes deleted projects. If you need to create a new API project and don't want to change the package name, you can also generate a new keystore file to sign your application and use its signing certificate fingerprint instead of the former one.